# How i can access mobile contact in salesforce 1 Application?

Tags: mobile

I want to access my all mobile contact in salesforce 1 . Only mobile contact that have mobile number. If contact contain email no mobile number then that contact not add in salesforce1.
thanku.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is only possible in native or hybrid app built using the Salesforce1 platform using the Cordova API. You cannot do this from your Visualforce pages from within Salesforce1 app container.